# Way to reference list names in R S3 object?

Tags: r, object, amazon-s3

I'm just learning how to create my own S3 object in R.  The class I'm creating is named **DAT**.  It contains a number of matrices that will be populated as the pre-processing of my data ensues.  Here's how I define it:

```
createDAT <- function(M){                # M is a data.matrix
   # it's assumed that samples are rows and genes are columns already
   z <- list(M_orig <- M,                     # assumed log2 scale
             M_nat <- matrix(),          # M_orig on natural scale
             M_filt <- matrix(),         # after gene filtering
             M_scaled <- matrix(),       # as fraction of all counts
             M_norm <- matrix(),         # after gene normalization
             ZEROGENES <- list(),
             outcome <- list(),
             RefSampleName <- character(),
             RefSample <- matrix(),
             RefSampleUnscaled <- matrix(),
             seed <- numeric())
   #names(z[[2]]) <- "Nat"
   class(z) <- "DAT"
   return(z)
}
```

I'll instantiate this here with the following code:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
df_wide <- t(df)
data <- createDAT(df_wide)
```

I have a list of "zero-expressed genes", called **ZERO**.  All I want to do is to add that list to the **data** instance of **DAT**.  I can successfully do that with the line:

```
data[[6]] <- ZERO
```

However, to make things more intuitive, instead of referencing data[[6]], I'd somehow like to use data$ZERO or something.

Is there some way of doing that?  I haven't been able to find anything online.

Thank you!!

Comment: Use `"[["`. It will accept a character argument. The `$` operator is just a crippled shorthand for "[[".

Comment: Thanks @42-.  That is helpful.  It still only worked if I changed the `<-` assign operator to an `=` operator as @gvegayon suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using arrows `<-` (assing operator) within the `list` function. Use equal signs instead and the elements in your DAT object will be named. That way you will be able to access to its elements using the `$` operator as you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you!  That solved my problem.  I really appreciate it.  I can't upvote yet, as I'm too new here.

Comment: I still think you can mark my post as selected answer :)